# fast-math cause undefined reference to `__pow_finite'

Tags: c++, c, clang, clang++, ubuntu-20.04

on ubuntu 20.04, when I use clang-8 or clang-9 (clang version 9.0.1-12) to compile a simple code containing reference to libm, it will fail with error "undefined reference to `__pow_finite`"

```
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double x=1, y=1;
    x = pow(x,y);
}
```

```
clang-9 -lm test.c -ffast-math
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-9b1a45.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'

readelf -Ws /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6| grep pow_finite
   626: 000000000002ed90    65 IFUNC   GLOBAL DEFAULT   17 __pow_finite@GLIBC_2.15
```

gcc is fine. Any idea what is wrong here?

c++ has the same problem:

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double x=1, y=1;
    x = pow(x,y);
}
```

**edit**

I actually used -lm, I just forgot to put in the text. If I do not add it, it is another error.

```
$ clang-9 test.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-3389a6.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `pow'

$ gcc test.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc21n4wb.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `pow'
```

F31 does not have this problem. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4r95od) is also fine. It must be something wrong on the system or specific subversion.

So far order does not matter, so I think it is not [gcc will not properly include math.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336477/gcc-will-not-properly-include-math-h):

```
clang-9 test.c -ffast-math -lm
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-6dfc29.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'

clang-9 -ffast-math test.c -lm
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/test-6754bc.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `__pow_finite'
```

change the ld to collect2 has the same problem, so it should not be ld's issue.

```
clang-9 -v -fuse-ld=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/collect2 test.c -ffast-math -lm
```

**update**

It seems related to [libc update](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=7bdb921d70bf9f93948e2e311fef9ef439314e41). There is no `math-finite.h` any more, so when `-ffast-math` generate `__*finite` it will fail. clang has to [change its behaviour](https://reviews.llvm.org/D74712).

Comment: I tried that already. Result is the same.

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate (as this question seems to deal with GCC: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8671366/10957435

Comment: @NateEldredge unfortunately it is not the case.

Comment: please noticed, if it is the order issue, it will say: `undefined reference to 'pow'` not `__pow_infinate`

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce that.

Comment: I agree that this looks like a bug with clang or glibc or Ubuntu 20.04's combination of them.  It works with clang-10 if that is an acceptable alternative.

Comment: unfortunately I have to stick to clang-9 so far.

Comment: Try running the `gcc` command with `-v`. It should tell you what dirs it searches and what libm it used. Because you're using an explicit version (e.g. `clang-9`), you may be getting the _wrong_ libm [for an older/newer version]. You could also run under `strace`. You may need `-L` and/or `-rpath` options to force linkage to the correct [version specific] libs. You can run `nm` or `readelf/objdump` on the various libm files to see which define the missing `__pow_infinite` symbol

Comment: @CraigEstey not the case. It turns out clang-9 does not work with new glibc which drops the `math-finite.h`

Comment: @Wang: Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: @Wang I've faced this issue too. Any solution so far?

Comment: @pmor as I described it is a compiler bug. It was fixed in later version. Just pick some up-to-date clang version. That's it.

Comment: @Wang Yes, now I understand. I've switched to Clang 10.0.0. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;TR: This was a bug in clang which fix in clang-10. If anyone has the same problem please either use the latest GCC or Clang version or set `-fno-finite-math-only`.

The root cause of this is clang wrongly called some non-API functions in libm:

> They were only ever an ABI (selected by use of -ffinite-math-only or
> options implying it, which resulted in the headers using "asm" to redirect
> calls to some libm functions), not an API. The change means that ABI has
> turned into compat symbols (only available for existing binaries, not for
> anything newly linked, not included in static libm at all, not included in
> shared libm for future glibc ports such as RV32), so, yes, in any case
> where tools generate direct calls to those functions (rather than just
> following the "asm" annotations on function declarations in the headers),
> they need to stop doing so.

Bug had been tracked [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D74712) and fixed with [PR](https://reviews.llvm.org/D74712) already in clang-10 for very long time.

For some more context on why these were removed see [Proposal: Remove or reduce math-finite.h](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-alpha/2019-03/msg00395.html):

> For some of the functions in this file; pow, powf, log, logf, log2, log2f,
> exp, expf, exp2, and exp2f; the default implementations have been improved
> to handle the special cases and the *_finite names are just aliases of the
> normal name and so the asm attribute isn't accomplishing anything.

Answer (score -1):

Add header files when compiling, `clang -L/home/xiaokuan/lib/glibc-2.32-install/lib -I/home/xiaokuan/lib/glibc-2.32-install/include -lm -ffast-math a.c`