# Compiling using multiple headerfiles in GCC -- undefined reference to .. math

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I've been working on this for a while now. I have these files:

```
main.c
zSim.h 
zSim.c
zDynamicArray.h 
zDynamicArray.c
zOptions.h 
zOptions.c
zMain.h 
zMain.c
```

All of the files and headers are located within the same folder.

My main has the following includes:

```
#include "zDynamicArray.h"
#include "zOptions.h"
#include "zMain.h"
#include "zSim.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

I am using header guards. Just for example, this is from my zSim.h file:

```
#ifndef SIM_H
#define SIM_H
#include "zDynamicArray.h"
#include "zOptions.h"

//This Header is accountable
//for all Simulation Related things. 

int Simulate(SIMOPT so,PRINTOPT po);

#endif
```

and this is a snippet from my zSim.c code (maybe I am doing something wrong here?):

```
#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#include "zSim.h"
#include "zDynamicArray.h"
#include "zOptions.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

I am compiling using this gcc command:

```
gcc main.c zSim.c zOptions.c zDynamicArray.c zMain.c -o TEST
```

and I also used:

```
cc -c main.c
cc -c zSim.c
cc -c ... etc
cc *.o -o TEST
```

They all result in an undefined reference for anything in the math.h library. Also when I use the `gcc -I` command, math is still undefined.

If i compile using `gcc main.c`, I get unresolved references for anything in my header files.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `-lm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try ading `-lm` at the end : `gcc  -c main.c cc -c zSim.c cc -c ... etc cc *.o -o TEST  -lm`

You have to link the math library with the -lm option. The reason why is explained here : [Why do you have to link the math library in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

> they all result in an undefined reference for anything in the math.h library

`math.h` is only the header file which contains prototypes and type declarations. You also need to **link** against the math library when creating your executable. Add `-lm` to your gcc call:

```
gcc main.c zSim.c zOptions.c zDynamicArray.c zMain.c -o TEST -lm
```

See also [Undefined reference to `sin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005363/undefined-reference-to-sin-in-c).